# Why the second RecyclerView is not working?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm using two firebase UI Recycler views in a single activity. The first recycler view is working fine but I don't know why the second Recycler view is not populating. One thing I noticed that in the second recycler view 'OnBind' and 'OnCreate' methods are not called up?
Basically, I'm trying to use two horizontal recycler views within a single activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Video> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Video, MyViewHolder> adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewVideo;

    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Meme> optionsForHindiJokes;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Meme, MyViewHolder> adapterForHindiJokes;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewForHindiJokes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerViewVideo = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_video);
        recyclerViewVideo.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewVideo.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));

        recyclerViewForHindiJokes = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_hindi_jokes);
        recyclerViewForHindiJokes.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewForHindiJokes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

     /*   **/

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference refToVideo1 = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://memlo-a9291-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/AppStructure/Videos/Video");
        refToVideo1.keepSynced(true);
        Query refToVideo = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://memlo-a9291-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/AppStructure/Videos/Video").limitToLast(20);

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Video>().setQuery(refToVideo, Video.class).build();

        adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Video, MyViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Video model) {
                RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_memlo_without_background);
                requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_memlo_without_background);

                Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(model.getVideoUrl())
                        .apply(requestOptions)
                        .thumbnail(Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(model.getVideoUrl()))
                   //     .centerCrop()
                        .into(holder.imageOnCard);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoPlayer.class);
                        intent1.putExtra("VIDEO_URL", model.getVideoUrl());
                        startActivity(intent1);

                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_cards_layout, parent, false);

                return new MyViewHolder(v);
            }
        };

        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerViewVideo.setAdapter(adapter);


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Query refToHindiJokes = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://memlo-a9291-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/AppStructure/Memes/Category/Hindi%20Jokes");
        optionsForHindiJokes = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Meme>().setQuery(refToHindiJokes, Meme.class).build();

        adapterForHindiJokes = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Meme, MyViewHolder>(optionsForHindiJokes) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Meme model) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Calling", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(model.getImageUrl())
                        .into(holder.imageOnCard);

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View v1=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_cards_layout, parent,false);
                return new MyViewHolder(v1);
            }
        };

        adapterForHindiJokes.startListening();
        adapterForHindiJokes.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerViewForHindiJokes.setAdapter(adapterForHindiJokes);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary codes :)

Comment: in getItemCount try returning your arraylist's size

Comment: @Shashank tried but no luck!

Comment: So... your toast saying "Calling" does not show up?

Comment: @MonsterDruide1 Yup, its not showing